# Ошибка при реализации массива компонентов(делфи)

Tags: массивы, компоненты

Прошу разъяснить что к чему... Вроде код написан верно но выскакивает ошибка!
(прошу взгляните) http://www.image.kg/images/2013/05/18/SBgOl.jpg

Comment: всё, разобрался... извиняюсь за глупый вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в границе цикла. `ControlCount` - это для массива `Controls`. Для `Components` граница называется `ComponentCount`.

Comment: да, там я опечатался случайно.. но исправление на form1.componentcount увы ничего не даёт... та же ошибка...(почти та же... адрес только её поменялся)